Format Number In Indian Style In SSRS
This patterns works for large digits like - 596478
Pattern - "##,##,##0.00;"
Output - 49,82,734.00
But if the value is 88460, it returns
Pattern - "##,##,##0.00;"
Output - ,0.00
Why is the ',' printing ! How can i avoid that?
Format value in custom format - ##,##,##0.00;
Number Format

You can do this easily by clicking on the report (a blank part outside the body) and the in the report properties, set the language to whatever you need. In this case I set it to en-IN.

Once you have done that then simply set the textbox number format to currency , you should see the correct currency symbols etc already in place based on the language you chose.

Here's a simple report with a bunch of numbers in both the raw format and with the currency format applied.


Thanks a lot sir .. Thank you for your help .

If this solved your problem ,please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left near the vote up/down buttons). This marks the question as answered and gives you reputation which means you can do more on SO as your reputation increases. It also helps other when looking for solutions to similar questions.
